# Post_Back fires OnSelectedIndexChanged no matter what

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

EDIT: I fixed the issue by creating a new ashx page with the code to download the pdf. I then open in it a new window which triggers the download.

---

I have a dropdown list inside a gridview. The list has hardcoded values and fires ChangeSelection() when the Index is changed.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSkilagreinar" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="False"> 
     <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="true" HeaderText="foo">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListAdgerd" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ChangeSelection">
          <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

On the same page I also have a button and a couple of LinkButtons. When I change the selection in the dropdownlist on the page it fires correctly, if I select "2" from it I can catch it and do what I want with it inside the ChangeSelection function. In this case I am triggering a PDF download.

However, If I now press the Button on the page, or the LinkButtons, they will fire the OnSelectedIndexChanged function again and again, which I do not want. The button has an OnClick attribute which calls he Button_Click function, but it never gets called If I have previously changed the dropdown index.

What is causing this issue? I have tried making the selected value "1" in the ChangeSelection function, after I am done processing the "2" selection, in hope of resetting the dropdownlist but it never happens.

I get the feeling that I need to reset the dropdown list somehow, but I am not sure how to go about it.

EDIT: When I select "2" from the dropdown list I call a function that initiates a PDF download with the following code:

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name_of_file);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes_to_be_downloaded);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

If I remove the call to this function everything works fine, except I don't get my PDF file. I can now press the button and LinkButtons and they do as expected, even though "2" is still selected. Am I missing something from the HttpContext calls?

Comment: Why have you set `EnableViewState=false`, try to enable it.

Comment: I have to go with @TimSchmelter here. The list is getting reloaded every time a post back occurs (likely by you) and so the index is in fact changing and thus firing. I'm only guessing, but there's probably code in `Load` that's rebuilding that drop down.

Comment: Neither true or false seems to work.

Comment: We need to see the Load event or any other code from the code behind file where you set anything on DropDownListAdgerd.

Comment: I do not do anything in Page_Load if there is postback. I press a button which generates the gridview which the dropdownlist is a part off.